# How to customize baidu push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using baidu push notification in my app. The issues i am facing are i am not able to customize its notification UI and not able to clear it from status bar unless i tap on that. I could see below code in theirs demo project to customize the UI. But it does not make any difference. please help me.

```
CustomPushNotificationBuilder cBuilder = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.notification_custom_builder,
                R.id.notification_icon, R.id.notification_title,
                R.id.notification_text);
        cBuilder.setNotificationFlags(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

        cBuilder.setNotificationDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        cBuilder.setStatusbarIcon(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().icon);
        cBuilder.setNotificationTitle("push");
        cBuilder.setNotificationText("baidu");
        PushManager.setNotificationBuilder(getApplicationContext(), 1, cBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this question. Actually the second parameter i pass in  PushManager.setNotificationBuilder(getApplicationContext(), 1, cBuilder); is notification ID. Means if u want to display a custom UI from server this id should be passed with notification. Then client will take corresponding builder with that ID. In my case i was not getting this parameter from server

Comment: Exactly how did you send this parameter from the server? I have a hard time deciphering the docs

Answer (score 0):

you can pass setNotificationTitle("notification_title"); and setNotificationText("notification_content"); this two parameter is fixed from baidu push notification server