# Disable default notifications in Push Baidu

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, baidu

I want to disable notifications in order to manage them myself. 
I tried to play with notification id for instance `PushManager.setNotificationBuilder(this, 2, cBuilder);` but it doesn't help.

How can I do turn the notifications off?

Note: [this question isn't an answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937100/how-to-customize-baidu-push-notification) but if you know how to *really* customize notifications, I mean add actions to them for example - your answer is appreciated too.

Comment: ..have you found the answer for disabling the custom notifications?

Comment: @BMM no, mate. I tried to decompile it and play with the sources but it's really tricky so I decided to use pushy.me

Comment: ..thanks for the reply...

Comment: Any luck in resolving this issue? I am trying to do the same.