# How to disable Baidu default notification

Tags: android, push-notification, baidu

I am able to successfully register and receive Baidu push notification.
Based on the payload I receive, I wanted to show my custom notification. But I am not able to disable the default notification, Baidu is showing in the notification bar when a notification arrives.
I tried by subclassing the PushMessageReceiver and overriding onMessage and onNotificationArrived, but none of them worked.
Is there any way to disable the Baidu default notification?

Comment: Even i found the fllowing post about the same but not helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748817/disable-default-notifications-in-push-baidu

Comment: any solution ? am looking for same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the payload body attribute as message or vice versa to change from default to regular notification

Comment: @RaviKumar...Can you send a sample payload which solved the issue for you?