# How do I get an button Onclicklistener in class for Android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I am developing `Baidu notification` in Android. The `Baidu notification` has no `Button`. So I decide to create custom `Baidu notification` and add the `Button` on it.

I pass an id to a `Class` and set it to the `Button`. I want to implement `OnCLickListener` and get click event in a `Class`.

In **`Activity`** , I use the following code to pass the id of `button` to **`customNoti`** class.

```
private fun initMyCustomNotiBuilder() {
        val customNoti = CustomNoti(
            R.layout.notification_custom_builder,
            R.id.notification_icon,
            R.id.notification_title,
            R.id.notification_text,
            R.id.btn_OK,this
        )
    }
```

The code is like the following

```
class CustomNoti : CustomPushNotificationBuilder, View.OnClickListener{

    lateinit var btn:Button
    lateinit var context:Context

    companion object{
        const val TAG = "CustomNoti"
    }

    constructor(layoutId: Int, layoutIconId: Int, layoutTitleId: Int, layoutTextId: Int, buttonID: Int,context: Context) : super(layoutId, layoutIconId, layoutTitleId, layoutTextId){
        this.context = context
        btn = Button(context)
        btn.id = buttonID
        btn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onClick view:${view?.id}")
    }
}
```

The `Baidu notification` has button now , but the `clicklistener` is not working when I click the button.

How do I get an `Onclicklistener` in class ?

Did I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You have created the button but that's not added to any view/viewgroup. You have to add it to a view to receive click event.

To find view by id in `CustomNoti` you can do the following in the constructor.

```
constructor(layoutId: Int, layoutIconId: Int, layoutTitleId: Int, layoutTextId: Int, buttonID: Int,context: Context) : super(layoutId, layoutIconId, layoutTitleId, layoutTextId){
    this.context = context
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, null)
    btn = view.findViewById(buttonID)
    btn.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

Comment: This would have been better under the comments section.

Comment: I understand , the button is in `R.layout.notification_custom_builder`. But how to add it to a view ?

Comment: If the button is already in `R.layout.notification_custom_builder` and laid out properly you don't have to  recreate it using this line `btn = Button(context)`, just get the object reference using `findById` and set `onClickListener` to that.

Comment: but it has not findById in class.

Comment: Please, check the updated answer to see how you can use `findViewId` in `CustomNoti` class

Comment: I have try , but the `onClick` has not been called when I click the `button` on `Baidu notification`.

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937100/how-to-customize-baidu-push-notification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195389/discussion-between-minhazur-and-wun).